# Apache.NMS.WCF

Tags: wcf, activemq-classic

Just curious if anyone has messed with the Apache.NMS.WCF code at all.  For a work project, I've started to try to integrate the Apache.NMS WCF binding with ActiveMQ.  I've made some progress, but if anyone has any links or info, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm interested in trying this as well. I was able to compile the NMS WCF code using .net 4 and visual studio 2010, but I have no idea how to configure it.

Comment: Yeah, I remember it being a bit confusing, but the last time I looked at it was about 2 years ago.  Based on Tim Bush's comment below, it sounds like there isn't anyone really maintaining it right now, so it might be a bit of a dead end unless something changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache.NMS.WCF project hasn't had anyone actively maintaining it for some time now, we'd really love to have someone contribute to that NMS provider.  Any docs or examples you come up with I can add to the Wiki site.  I've not had much experience with WCF myself or I'd try and help.